# "No WebApplicationContext found" error when adding css/js files to index.jsp

Tags: css, spring, jsp

First, I want to apologize in advance if this question was already answered somewhere but I couldn't find a reasonable solution, and I would also say that's mainly because I'm pretty new to Java Spring Framework. I managed to deploy a simple application myself and I added some css/js files as well. However, specifically in the index.jsp file, I always receive:

> "ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.UrlTag - No
>   WebApplicationContext found: not in a DispatcherServlet request and no
>   ContextLoaderListener registered? java.lang.IllegalStateException: No
>   WebApplicationContext found: not in a DispatcherServlet request and no
>   ContextLoaderListener registered?"

when adding these lines to the template:

```
<spring:url value="/resources/example1/css/main.css" var="mainCss" />
<link href="${mainCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This is my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>example1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>example1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my `example1-servlet.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example1.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/example1"  
    cache-period="31556926"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

This is my `index.jsp`

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <spring:url value="/resources/example1/css/main.css" var="mainCss" /> 
    <link href="${mainCss}" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<%--    <spring:url value="/resources/example1/css/main.css" var="mainCss" /> --%>
<%--    <spring:url value="/resources/example1/js/main.js" var="mainJs" /> --%>
<%--    <spring:url value="/resources/example1/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" var="jqueryJs" /> --%>

<%--    <link href="${mainCss}" rel="stylesheet" /> --%>
<%--     <script src="${jqueryJs}"></script> --%>
<%--     <script src="${mainJs}"></script> --%>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, this is my file structure:

```
/WebContent
    /META-INF
    /resources
        /example1
            /css
                -main.css  
            /js
                -main.js
                -jquery-2.2.3.min.js  
    /WEB-INF
        /jsp
            -welcome.jsp
        -example1-servlet.xml
        -web.xml  
    -index.jsp
```

with the other template (welcome.jsp), everything runs fine when adding the same resource files. Any ideias?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need add listener **org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener** in **web.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>example1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>example1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```